# Istio - Block certain IPs to access services

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress

I want to block certain IP list to access services. For that I am using below code but it's giving me `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`. Am I doing something wrong? Istio Policy is set up correctly. I checked with the given example code which was working fine but I want to block external IP.

**yaml**

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: blacklistip
spec:
  compiledAdapter: listchecker
  params:
    # providerUrl: ordinarily black and white lists are maintained
    # externally and fetched asynchronously using the providerUrl.
    overrides: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]  # overrides provide a static list
    blacklist: true
    entryType: IP_ADDRESSES
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: clientip
spec:
  compiledTemplate: listentry
  params:
    value: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: checkip
spec:
  match: source.labels["istio"] == "ingressgateway"
  actions:
  - handler: blacklistip
    instances: [ clientip ]
```

I checked istioingressgateway logs:

```
{"bytes_sent":"95","upstream_cluster":"outbound|3000||api.default.svc.cluster.local","downstream_remote_address":"xx.xx.xx.xx:59762","authority":"api.example.com","path":"/core/csrf","protocol":"HTTP/2","upstream_service_time":"-","upstream_local_address":"-","duration":"1","downstream_local_address":"10.2.0.14:443","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","route_name":"-","response_code":"503","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36","response_flags":"UC","start_time":"2020-01-15T16:32:21.634Z","method":"GET","request_id":"353149b6-0749-4a1a-9348-4016d20215de","upstream_host":"10.2.0.33:3000","x_forwarded_for":"xx.xx.xx.xx","requested_server_name":"api.example.com","bytes_received":"0","istio_policy_status":"-"}
```

Istio proxy logs within the pod:

```
{"authority":"-","path":"-","protocol":"-","upstream_service_time":"-","upstream_local_address":"127.0.0.1:53894","duration":"0","downstream_local_address":"10.2.0.33:3000","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","route_name":"-","response_code":"0","user_agent":"-","response_flags":"-","start_time":"2020-01-15T17:21:25.220Z","method":"-","request_id":"-","upstream_host":"127.0.0.1:3000","x_forwarded_for":"-","requested_server_name":"outbound_.3000_._.api.default.svc.cluster.local","bytes_received":"0","istio_policy_status":"-","bytes_sent":"0","upstream_cluster":"inbound|3000|https|api.default.svc.cluster.local","downstream_remote_address":"10.2.0.14:37126"}
```

Istio Version: 1.4.2

**mixer logs**

```
2020-01-15T22:48:47.633162Z error   evaluation failed at [sourceip.instance.default]'Value': 'lookup failed: 'request.headers''
2020-01-15T22:48:47.633192Z error   error creating instance: destination='listentry:whitelistip.default(listchecker)', error='evaluation failed at [sourceip.instance.default]'Value': 'lookup failed: 'request.headers'''
2020-01-15T22:48:47.633204Z error   api Check failed: performing check operation failed: 1 error occurred:
* evaluation failed at [sourceip.instance.default]'Value': 'lookup failed: 'request.headers''
```

Comment: Logs of istio proxy sidecar running along your application pod

Comment: along with that error message are you getting any error code such as 503?

Comment: are you using nginx ingress ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu: Updated question with proxy logs. I am using `istio ingressgateway`. In browser I only see `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`.

Comment: Also, it works when I replace this `value: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"` with `value: source.ip | ip("0.0.0.0")`. But, I want to use client IP in my usecase.

Answer (score 1):

For `x-forwarded-for` to work the gateway need to forward that header to the istio-proxy sidecar running along with your application pod.

You need to do some configuration in gateway to forward that. Check [this issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19075) which refers to other issues with details on how to do it.

If you have option to use nginx ingress instead of istio ingress then You can use `request.headers["x-real-ip"]` which is set by nginx based on [configuration](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/proxy-protocol)

Comment: I am getting client IP in `x-forwarded-for` but somehow it's not recognized by mixer. Please see updated question. I added mixer logs.

Comment: "x_forwarded_for":"-" is not having ip

Comment: As you can see in logs it's present in `ingressgateway` but not in pod's proxy container. That means something is wrong in between.